# I want to return List<JSONObject> but it will return { "empty": false }

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<JSONObject>  search(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String a, @RequestParam(required = false) String b){
    List<JSONObject>listofcontact=new ArrayList<>();
    listofcontact=searchService.searchProcessing(a,b);
    return listofcontact;
```

When i put debugg point all data will show in listofcontact but it return  { "empty": false }

Comment: How about using `JSONArray` instead of a list of `JSONObject`?

Comment: Try using .add in your listofcontact instead of saving with equals (==).

Comment: @TrietDoan same using JSONArray { "empty": false }

Comment: Try hard-coding the `listofcontact` instead of calling to `searchService.searchProcessing(a,b)`. If the problem is still there, then maybe you have a wrong Spring Boot configuration somewhere. Otherwise, the `searchService.searchProcessing(a,b)` is the problem.